# Is it possible to use Hadoop on a single node to get a higher speed?

Tags: hadoop

I want to process some big files like word counting.

I just have a single workstation with 8 cores and 128GB memory.

Is it better to use standalone, pseudo distributed mode on Hadoop or not to use Hadoop but research the concurrecency?

If using Hadoop is better, is there any thumb of rule to decide the configuration including number of mapper, reducer, etc. on a single workstation?

2014-03-02

Here is the information for my hard disks:

NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdc                         8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sdc1                      8:33   0   255M  0 part
├─sdc2                      8:34   0     8G  0 part
├─sdc3                      8:35   0     8G  0 part
├─sdc4                      8:36   0    16G  0 part
│ └─md3                     9:3    0  15.3G  0 raid1 /
├─sdc5                      8:37   0    32G  0 part
│ └─md127                   9:127  0    64G  0 raid5 
│   └─vg01-scratch (dm-0) 252:0    0  63.9G  0 lvm   /local/scratch
├─sdc6                      8:38   0    64G  0 part
├─sdc7                      8:39   0   128G  0 part
├─sdc8                      8:40   0   256G  0 part
├─sdc9                      8:41   0     1T  0 part
│ └─md125                   9:125  0     2T  0 raid5 
│   └─vg03-data (dm-1)    252:1    0     4T  0 lvm   /local/cargobay
└─sdc10                     8:42   0     1T  0 part
  └─md126                   9:126  0     2T  0 raid5 
    └─vg03-data (dm-1)    252:1    0     4T  0 lvm   /local/cargobay
sda                         8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0   255M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0     8G  0 part
├─sda3                      8:3    0     8G  0 part
├─sda4                      8:4    0    16G  0 part
│ └─md3                     9:3    0  15.3G  0 raid1 /
├─sda5                      8:5    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md127                   9:127  0    64G  0 raid5 
│   └─vg01-scratch (dm-0) 252:0    0  63.9G  0 lvm   /local/scratch
├─sda6                      8:6    0    64G  0 part
├─sda7                      8:7    0   128G  0 part
├─sda8                      8:8    0   256G  0 part
├─sda9                      8:9    0     1T  0 part
│ └─md125                   9:125  0     2T  0 raid5 
│   └─vg03-data (dm-1)    252:1    0     4T  0 lvm   /local/cargobay
└─sda10                     8:10   0     1T  0 part
  └─md126                   9:126  0     2T  0 raid5 
    └─vg03-data (dm-1)    252:1    0     4T  0 lvm   /local/cargobay
sdb                         8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sdb1                      8:17   0   255M  0 part
├─sdb2                      8:18   0     8G  0 part
├─sdb3                      8:19   0     8G  0 part
├─sdb4                      8:20   0    16G  0 part
│ └─md3                     9:3    0  15.3G  0 raid1 /
├─sdb5                      8:21   0    32G  0 part
│ └─md127                   9:127  0    64G  0 raid5 
│   └─vg01-scratch (dm-0) 252:0    0  63.9G  0 lvm   /local/scratch
├─sdb6                      8:22   0    64G  0 part
├─sdb7                      8:23   0   128G  0 part
├─sdb8                      8:24   0   256G  0 part
├─sdb9                      8:25   0     1T  0 part
│ └─md125                   9:125  0     2T  0 raid5 
│   └─vg03-data (dm-1)    252:1    0     4T  0 lvm   /local/cargobay
└─sdb10                     8:26   0     1T  0 part
  └─md126                   9:126  0     2T  0 raid5 
    └─vg03-data (dm-1)    252:1    0     4T  0 lvm   /local/cargobay
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop might save you some development time because you can use scripting like PIG or SQL (Hive) to do the processing. But it is definitely not the most efficient way to get single node parallelization - starting from all the overhead of running the hadoop processes, the fact that hadoop parallelization is multi-process based and not multi-threaded, most Hadoop technologies (not all) are disk oriented not memory etc.

Hadoop is designed to solve big data problems not local single machine ones

Comment: Many thanks. So the advantage for using Hadoop on a single node is saving developing time. It is efficient in some cases but not the best one. Is there any suggestion if I do not use Hadoop or using Hadoop on single node?

Comment: Generally speaking the only reason to use Hadoop on a single node is if you are doing that for development/testing purposes and your real target is a large cluster of machines

Answer (score 0):

Until you use at least 8 hard disks for HDFS on this machine Hadoop will not give you any benefit.

Comment: Therefore the relation is one core needs at least one hard disk?

Comment: It depends on the task you solve, but basically Hadoop was developed with intensive disk access in mind. If you don't do it, then you waste your money using Hadoop on your hardware. In my opinion, one of the best universal configurations for Hadoop cluster is 1 HDD per CPU core and 2GB of RAM per 1 CPU Core.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop on the single node cluster will not give the power of real hadoop for that you need a at least small grid of 2 - 3 system for getting real power of hadoop. Single node hadoop cluster is only good for the learning purposes but for the real time at least have a grid of 2 -3 systems.